# How to dynamically resize a label in a window size

Tags: kivy

I have a problem in kivy file where my label doesn't fit into the window whenever I resize the window the problem I get is shown in the image

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrxC8.png)

I tried using size_hint property but nothing Happens...

```html
<ForgotPasswordGridLayoutDesign>:
    cols:1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1  # White color (RGBA format)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        text: "Forgot Password"
        font_size: '50dp'
        color: .2,.5,.7,.7
        size_hint: (1,None)
        markup: True
    TextInput:
        hint_text: "Enter username here"
        singleline:True
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: "30dp"
        spacing: 10
    Button:
        text: "Confirm"
        size_hint: .4,None
        height: "30dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the `font_size` of the `Label` to reduce the `font_size` when the `Label` `size` gets smaller. A simple hack is to add to the `Label`:

```
font_size: min(50, self.width/10)
```

Of course, you can do things more complex. Perhaps calling a method to calculate the preferred `font_size`:

```
on_size: app.adjust_font_size(self)
```

Then, in the `App`:

```
def adjust_font_size(self, label):
    print('in adjust font size, label font size is', label.font_size, ', adjust to fit width of', label.width)
```